# Quick Java Optimization Question

Tags: java, eclipse, optimization, compiler-construction

Will the Eclipse compiler automatically convert multiplication by a power of two into a bit shift, or should I do that manually? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Short answer: No. The source code compiler won't replace a multiplication by two with a bit shift.

Long answer: It won't, because it can't know if a bit shift is faster than a multiplication on the platform the code eventually will be running. So, the question should rather be if a specific VM will replace the multiplication with a bit shift, and it probably will. I experimented a little bit with this to optimize a code block and it's interesting that Sun's Hotspot shows different behaviour here, depending on if the program runs on an AMD or on an Intel CPU (at least with the CPUs I tested). In either case, a multiplication with a power of two is replaced with a bit shift, but for multiplications with a power of two +/- 1 (3, 5, 7, 9, 15, 17, ...), Hotspot will generate a bit shift and an addition or a subtraction for Intel CPUs, while generating a multiplication for AMD CPUs, since the AMD CPU executes a multiplication much faster than the Intel CPU. It's of course possible, that this behaviour differs between different CPU models from each vendor.

If you are interested in knowing what the VM actually is doing, it is quite benefical to get the debug build of jdk7 and enable dumps of the assembler code generated by the Hotspot compiler.

Answer (score 9):

**Don't second guess a modern java compiler unless you know exactly what you are doing.**  This not only applies to simple math like you question, but everything.  E.g.: like flow control.

People waaaaay smarter than us have put lots of effort into making it all super fast.

Comment: How is asking == second guessing?

Comment: @HRJ When it becomes a matter of premature optimization

Comment: I don't see how you could infer that this is a case of "premature optimization". Moreover, the question is not just relevant for the OP's case, but for many other cases that visitors of StackOverflow may have.

Comment: @HJR: I read into the original question, answered accordingly.  Hence why the OP selected my answer as correct--he was trying to optimize, the question was not merely academic.  Other visitors can read jarnbjo's answer and vote it up (like I did.)  My answer in no way detracts from that.  Both answers can valuable to future visitors.  StackOverflow does not require there to be The One True Answer That Rules Them All.

Answer (score 4):

In general you cannot outsmart the JVM unless there is something very high level *you* know that cannot be deduced automatically.  This usually means a better algorithm is available than the one which is currently used instead of having to handtweak your source.  You can use the jvisualvm profiler available in the latest Java 6 JDK's to investigate your program and see where the bottlenecks are.

For instance, the expense of creating new objects instead of reusing old ones has diminished radically then last 10 years, so you should not take any old advice for tuning your java program without examining if it still holds.

You will, however, find that keeping your program simple and above all - readable - will make it much easier to maintain both for you and for future programmers.  Any unneccessary complexity will baffle  your future readers, and you will need to say in a comment why it MUST be like that (otherwise they will just refactor it back into its original form :)